# Grunt is insanely slow on a clean yeoman angular-generate setup

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm a grunt newbie. My PC runs Windows 7 x64.

I followed the Yeoman tutorial (on the Yeoman site) and I did not change anything in any of the generated files. Then, I ran

```
grunt serve
```

When I change any html file, the grunt process is instantaneous, but when I modify one of the .js or .css files, the process is insanely slow. When I hit save, grunt notices it immediately  :

```
>> File "app\styles\index.css" changed
```

But there seems to be around 4 long seconds before the next lines appear on the terminal :

```
Running "newer:copy:styles" (newer) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
Copied 1 files

Running "newer-timestamp:copy:styles:R:\Personnel\Workspaces\web\front\plume\node_modules\grunt-newer\.cache" (newer-timestamp)
task

Running "newer-reconfigure:copy:styles:1" (newer-reconfigure) task

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/index.css" created.
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/main.css" created.

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2014-03-21 00:00:19 UTC)
loading tasks                                            6ms  ■■■■■ 9%
newer:copy:styles                                        9ms  ■■■■■■■■ 14%
copy:styles                                              7ms  ■■■■■■ 11%
newer-timestamp:copy:style...odules\grunt-newer\.cache   3ms  ■■■ 5%
autoprefixer                                             1ms  ■ 2%
autoprefixer:dist                                       39ms  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 59%
Total 66ms
... Reload .tmp\styles\index.css ...
... Reload .tmp\styles\main.css ...
Completed in 4.463s at Fri Mar 21 2014 01:00:20 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid) -
```

Waiting...

I'm confused. grunt says it took him 66ms total to run the tasks, but then it says that it took him 4.463s to complete the whole process.

What did I did wrong ? The build is clean, I did nothing else than

```
yo angular
```

To scaffold the app... Any idea ?

edit : 

`spawn: false`

Solved my problem. Thanks to the one who brought that up. Even if I use Gulp or webpack nowadays.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this in my linux environment, but it was fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `spawn` option that sometimes make things faster --and also more prone to failing apparently.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsspawn):

> Whether to spawn task runs in a child process. Setting this option to
>   false speeds up the reaction time of the watch (usually 500ms faster
>   for most) and allows subsequent task runs to share the same context.
>   Not spawning task runs can make the watch more prone to failing so
>   please use as needed.

You would disable the spawn adding a `options` section inside `watch` in your Gruntfile.js. Something like this.

```
watch: {
  options: {
    spawn: false
  },
```

Comment: Usemin is not (yet) really compatible with spawn:false. Details: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/307

Comment: yep, `spawn: false` made the process considerably faster. I'm gonna stick with that for now. Thanks.